# Swift - Why does my UIButton need to be double tapped to be in its selection state?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UIButton, and the expected behavior is when it is tapped, it should be have the blue background color, and when untapped, it should be white. However, I always have to double tap it on the first try for it to become selected... why is that?

```
class CheckmarkCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier = String(describing: CheckmarkCell.self)

    @IBOutlet private weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var yesButton: UIButton!

    private weak var delegate: CheckmarkCellDelegate?
    private var value: Bool?

    public func configure(title: String, value: Bool?, delegate: CheckmarkCellDelegate? = nil) {
        self.titleLabel.text = title
        self.value = value
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.yesButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.yesButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.yesButton.frame.width / 2
        self.yesButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.yesButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.NBABlue?.cgColor
        self.yesButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            // This is the dot
        self.yesButton.tintColor = UIColor.clear

        // This block of code saves the values. If it is removed, when you scroll, values will all be deselected and false.
        switch self.value {
        case true:
            // This is the saved state
            self.yesButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.NBABlue
            self.yesButton.tintColor = UIColor.clear

            // Deselected, should e white.
        case false:
            self.yesButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.yesButton.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.isSelected {
            yesButton.isSelected = false
                // The selected state
            self.yesButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.NBABlue
            self.yesButton.tintColor = UIColor.clear
            if self.value == nil || self.value == false {
                self.value = true
                self.delegate?.checkmarkCell(self, selectedValue: self.value!)
            }
        } else {
            yesButton.isSelected = true
            self.yesButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.yesButton.tintColor = UIColor.clear
            if self.value == nil || self.value == true {
                self.value = false
                self.delegate?.checkmarkCell(self, selectedValue: self.value!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do something similar in an extension called `toggleOn()` and `toggleOff()`. Here's the thing that's probably missing win your question - but it also could be what's also missing in your code. How is `isSelected` initially set up? If on first tap it has to set it to false, well, that means to set it to true would take two taps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remove blue background you have to clear tint colour from storyboard.

In section file IBAction write this line.

```
sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
```

Comment: this works, but it does not allow my to deselect anymore

Comment: Then for select deSelect you can write code in condition like                                        if sender.isSelected { selected } else {deselect}